# Match 2nd occurrence with regex

Tags: regex, ip

In a syslog string with the format a depicted below I want to get every time the second occurence of the characters between `/` and `(`:

```
<164>Feb 25 2019 17:25:31 FW-ATH : %ASA-4-106100: access-list foo_access_in denied tcp chicago/192.168.51.42(10050) -> new_york/192.168.65.71(59910) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0x3f890f86, 0x1a85d55c]
```

To be more precise, and in this case I want to get the `192.168.65.71`.
For the first internal IP, I have used the below regex but I don't know how to format it in order to capture the second internal IP

Regex: `(?<=\/)(.*?)(?=\()`

The format is `VLAN/IP_ADDRESS` so, i can not use new_york as part of the regex, the name is dynamic.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will use look arounds, then you will get all possible matches in the regex, because look arounds don't consume characters. If you want to skip matching the first IP, you can use `.*` before the regex instead of positive look behind and use this regex and capture the second occurrence of IP from group1,

```
.*\/(.*?)(?=\()
```

Here, `.*\/` captures any character in a greedy manner followed by a literal `/` and stops at last occurrence of the pattern you want to match and captures all data after `/` and before `(` and gives you the second occurrence of IP

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CtU8vc/1)**